# What type of value do I store in Firebase RTDB for the Path Class for a real time drawing app on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a real-time drawing app using `Firebase Realtime Database` with Android but I don't know how I should store the drawn list of `Path` on Firebase.

Right now on my Canvas, I am storing them as an `ArrayList<Path>` so that when a user draws, it adds a Path to the `Arraylist` and when they remove it, it would remove the last value.

What should I store the value as for a key in Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database stores JSON data, which means you can't store the path as is. Instead you will have to store the pieces that the path is made up from, as JSON data.

For example, in the [Firebase sample drawing app](https://github.com/googlearchive/AndroidDrawing), we stored a drawing as a list of polylines, and each polyline a list of points. We used [`push()` IDs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) to store the line segments, but that depends on your needs.

You will have to create a similar mapping from your list of paths to the database, and vice versa: reconstruct the list of paths from the database.